# Is a baby shower permissible?

Tags: halal-haram, practical-islam, islamic-basis, pregnancy

I didn't find any question regarding [baby showers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby_shower), so I'll first explain what a baby shower is: it is a celebration for a lady during her 5th or 7th month of pregnancy; In this function, bangles were wore to the lady for her full hands (thus we also call it a "bangle function").  I want to know whether Islam allows this function?

I need authentic answer because, now that I'm pregnant, my family people are planning to do so. My intuition is that Islam does not allow this kind of function. But I want proof that this is not allowed from hadith and Sunnah.

Comment: I'm a bit confused do you mean baby shower https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby_shower or bangle function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valaikaapu as you mentioned both, but they are definitely different, the common ground is that neither of them is related to Islam.

Comment: I didn't spot that when editing---my impression from the original question was that they were the same thing (but one with bangles instead of other gifts).  Perhaps it's worth having a separate question for "bangle functions" if they're different.